# How to pass statement ' i ' in {this.props.example[i]}

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When i have an actual value to declare my prop's array position it works fine. But using a loop method doesn't work because it isn't seeing the statement correctly.

```
render: function() {
for(var i = 0; i > 3; i++) {
  var test = {this.props.example[i]}
}
```

Results in nothing being displayed. Is there an alternative method for this to work?

Comment: You should return something from `render` function.

Comment: use `Array.map`

Answer (score 0):

you can write jsx in render method :

```
render : function()
{
 return
<div>
{
    for(var i = 0; i > 3; i++) {
      var test = this.props.example[i]
      console.log(test);
    }
}
</div>
}
```

I am assuming that example is array of integer.

Answer (score 0):

Map use of map and return an element from the render function. you can do this as

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.props.example.map(function(item, key){
             return <div key={key}>{item}</div>
           })}</div>
    )
  }
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      example : ["Hello", "Stack", "Overflow"]
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.state.example.map(function(item, key){
             return <div key={key}>{item}</div>
           })}</div>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```